# How to reuse the common variable name and function in all the component

Tags: angular

Using tab showing the components, each components will have a data grid to display the various data.

Top of the tab kept global search filter and edit icon.

To make a edit mode of the component crated the modeEdit variable in each component how can i update the appropriate component variable also how can we use the search filer to the  appropriate component data variable?

The below code is available in around 7 components,

```
showEdit() {
    if (this.showedit === true) {
      this.showedit = false;
    } else {
      this.showedit = true;
    }
    return this.showedit;
  }
```

Components data grid data's are available in this.info, how can we use the global search to the variable.

Comment: Your `showEdit()` does not quite convey what it does which is toggling a flag. Maybe a better method name is `toggleEdit()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a Service and Register the service with an Angular module rather than a component.

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [ AppComponent,],
  imports: [BrowserModule,],
  providers: [SharedService],
```

**Your Service**

```
export class SharedService {
    showEdit() {
        this.showedit =!this.showedit;
        return this.showedit;
    }
}
```

Inject it into your components and use

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private service: SharedService) {} 

    public data;

    ngOnInit() {
        this.data=this.service.showEdit();
    }
}
```

> from [Angular
>   docs](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection#ngmodule-or-component)
>
> Angular module providers `(@NgModule.providers)` are registered with the
>   application's root injector. Angular can inject the corresponding
>   services in any class it creates. Once created, a service instance
>   lives for the life of the app and Angular injects this one service
>   instance in every class that needs it.

**To summarize**

If you want an instance of a dependency to be shared globally and share `state` across the application  configure it on the `NgModule.`(Singleton)

If you want a separate instance of a dependency to be shared across each instance of a component and it’s children configure it on the components `providers` property.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the behavior subject as well

1) Create service

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {BehaviorSubject, Subject} from 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable()
export class MyService {
    public _showEdit: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject(false);
    public showEdit: Observable<boolean> = this._showEdit.asObservable();

    changeEditMode(): void {
        const newEditMode = !this._showEdit.getValue();
        this._showedit.next(newEditMode); // <-- save new value
    }
}
```

2) You can subscribe to this value in whatever component or service.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.myService.showEdit.subscribe(val => {
        this.showEdit = val;
    });
}
```

3) To change your value

```
this.myService.changeEditMode();
```

Answer (score 1):

Make use of inheritance!

```
// making it abstract so that BaseComponent cannot be used solely
export abstract class BaseComponent {
  showedit: boolean;
  showEdit() {
    if (this.showedit === true) {
      this.showedit = false;
    } else {
      this.showedit = true;
    }
    return this.showedit;
  }
}
```

Now in your components,

```
@Component({...})
export class ComponentOne extends BaseComponent {
   // base methods will be available!
   method() {
      this.showEdit();
   }
}
```

Comment: No relation ship between any of the components.

Comment: so what? there won't be any problem. extend your `BaseComponent` in all of your 6-7 components. the method will be available

Comment: edit button will be in tab component but the variable will be used in grid component, how come extending the tab component will update the grid component.   as per my understating inheritance goes in top to lower. thx

Comment: how would anybody know about that if you don't share your complete code? go through how to create [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried create a service? Services are singletone with a simple module declaration.

Comment: Service will communicate to all the component's, is't it?  If i use service all the component will come to edit mode I hope.

Comment: Nope, won't work. coz it will be singleton. Change of value in one component will make changes for all components.

Comment: If you declare the service in the component configuration, you will have a new instance of the service in each component.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a service which you can use any where in the project.

Create a service: **ng g s SystemSettings**

Than in service you can have your variables like:

```js
public GlobalSearch: string = "";
pubilc APIUrl: stirng = "";
```

Than in any of your component import the service

```js
import { SystemSettings } from '../../SystemSettings';
```

and in constructor

```js
constructor(public/private systemSettings: SystemSettings)
```